# Keeping Oracle data in sync with ElasticSearch cluster

Tags: java, database, oracle, elasticsearch, data-synchronization

My solution to sync Oracle data(updated by various systems) into ElasticSearch is to use triggers(insert/update) in the database table and insert event entry[table name and primary keys] into events table.

A listener fetches the events, locks it, fetches the data from Oracle database to index and then prepares JSON document to index into elasticsearch and indexes it using bulk API.

I was asked to redesign it like below,

- Listen to events (inserts/updates in Oracle).
- Post the event to SQS.
- SQS listener to fetch records from Oracle database using web service.
- Web service should have APIs to return record for the given primary key and with batching support for queries without primary keys(to fetch records from related tables - to prepare nested documents).
- SQS listener after fetching all necessary records for a given event, prepares the JSON document to index and indexes it in elasticsearch using bulk API.

I don't find the second approach to be the right solution for the near real-time applications, please help me understand the benefits of this approach.

Comment: I'd look into doing this with bulk operations in ES. Meaning, wait for a period of time - 30 seconds for example - gather all the events from Oracle, create one or multiple batches and send them via bulk to ES. But it depends I think. Your initial approach mentions "locks it" so there is the concern related to transactions...

Comment: Yes, indexing will happen through bulk API. Locking(using a separate column) the event to prevent other listeners from processing the same event.